# Display encoded html with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-encode

I store encoded HTML in the database.

The only way i could display it correctly is :

```
<div class='content'>    
   @MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content));
</div>
```

It's ugly.
Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class='content'>    
   @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content))
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is better, but still not what I looking for.

Comment: I ended up making an extension method according this idea.  @Html.RawDecode(Model.Content)

Comment: Just avoid ; in the end

Comment: This works but its so dirty... ended up making an Extention method with this wrapped, can someone explain why doesnt the .Raw just work?

Comment: Just be aware that this will introduce XSS vulnerabilities, so make sure you trust the input. If you need to store and render formatted text from users, use more suitable markup languages like markdown or some custom XML like editors.

Answer (score 50):

Use `Html.Raw()`.  Phil Haack posted a nice syntax guide at http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx.

```
<div class='content'>
    @Html.Raw( Model.Content )
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. But i think the Html.Raw() is 'display as it is, do not encode'. So if I use this, then I can't decode my html before I save it to the database. So it will display the user entered content without any 'security' check. So I think this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

this is pretty simple:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content)
```

Another Solution, you could also return a HTMLString, Razor will output the correct formatting:

in the view itself:

```
@Html.GetSomeHtml()
```

in controller:

```
public static HtmlString GetSomeHtml()
{
    var Data = "abc<br/>123";
    return new HtmlString(Data);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also simply use the `HtmlString` class

```
    @(new HtmlString(Model.Content))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I store encoded HTML in the database.

Imho you should not store your data html-encoded in the database. Just store in plain text (not encoded) and just display your data like this and your html will be automatically encoded:

```
<div class='content'>
    @Model.Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got another case to display backslash `\` with Razor and Java Script.

My `@Model.AreaName` looks like **Name1\Name2\Name3** so when I display it all backslashes are gone and I see **Name1Name2Name3**

I found solution to fix it:

```
var areafullName =  JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AreaName)))");
```

Don't forget to add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` on top of `chtml` page.