# Return html string from controller and display in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I return a model with a string propertie containing `<li>` elements and display it in view? 
If I just write @Model.Messages it shows all the string.. i need it in html format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't say which rendering engine you're using:

MVC3:
    @Html.Raw(Model.Description)

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `Content` method with the Content-Type `text/html` to return the HTML directly, without the need of `Html.Raw`.

```
public ActionResult MyHtmlView() {
    return Content("<html><body>Ahoy.</body></html>", "text/html")
}
```

You can pass whatever Content-Type you want, such `text/xml`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Server.HtmlEncode()` to send html to view and then use the `Server.HtmlDecode()` to get the html to display on the view.

Then you can use `@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(str)).`

Try this:

```
<div class='content'>     
   @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Message)); 
</div>
```

Ref:
[Display encoded html with razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor)