# .html and .append not encoding dynamic html from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using C# ASP.NET MVC, and wish to populate a DIV with html stored in a database. I have tried the following:

```
//getting a string of HTML from a database
@{
string myHtml = Model.Data.Html;
}

//Using Javascript to insert this into a Div
<script>
$("#myDiv").html("@myHtml");
</script>
```

The div fills with the html, but it is inserted as raw text and displays all of the html tags. I have tried .append and .html to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [the `@Html.Raw()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)?

```
$('#myDiv').html('@Html.Raw(myHtml)');
```

*Be careful* as this could be part of [an XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).  Don't directly render user input as unencoded HTML.  (This is exactly why the ASP.NET MVC Framework HTML-encodes output by default, which is the issue you're seeing.)

Comment: Thank you, this works. Fortunately my datasource does not accept user input!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#myDiv").html('@Html.Raw(Model.Data.Html)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an explicit requirement to use Javascript to do this, simply use Html.Raw to output unencoded HTML inline.

```
<div id="myDiv">@Html.Raw(myHtml)</div>
```