# How to Render decoded Html from razor view's Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, html-encode

I am trying to Set a textfields values as Raw Html so that it does not encode strings containing characters like single quotes. e.g. O'Riely is displayed as O & # 0 3 9 ; Riely.
The problem i have is I cannot use @html.Raw() function in the Javascript when I also reference a view Model field/mix up with c# code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         <text>
        $('#mytextField').val('@Model.FullName ');
        </text>
    });
</script>
```

Any Suggestion will be more then welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display encoded html with razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor), you can do this with `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.FullName));
```

Comment: My string(@Model.FullName) is not encoded However when its rendered on the page it shows as encoded html.
Another issue is that I am doing it in JQuery document.load and calling something like html.Raw ends in Jquery Error.
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier