# How to print out new lines from SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Let's say I have a this value in my database

```
"line 1 <br/> line 2 <br/> line 3"
```

When I display it through using select statement and paragraph tag like this

```
<p> @item.value </p>
```

it prints out the same single line. What should I insert to the values in the database in order to read the break lines tags ?

I tried to replace the `<br>` tags with `char(13)` / `char(10)+char(13)` / `\n` and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try using : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value)

Comment: @user3151766 im Not using MVC im building webpages with Razor syntax, it tells me that html helper does not contain DisplayFor

Comment: asp.net webpages with razor syntax

Comment: Could `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor)?