# jsReport - Embed HTML in MVC razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsreport

We have a series of reports that are built on the jsReport cloud instance.

Our primary app is an MVC app built on razor and C#.  I am able to use the jsReport.Client library to execute a report and retrieve the content as PDF.

I would like to display the rendered HTML within my Razor view.  Is there a way client-side or server-side to accomplish this?  There is a good deal of documentation on the jsReport site, but I haven't' found anything that addresses this scenario.

Comment: You are asking how to display html response from jsreport inside razor view? Why don't you pass it there in model?

Comment: Jan - I don't know how to accomplish this.  Can you provide an example project that demonstrates this functionality?

Comment: You may try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5031069/1660996 However you should reformulate your question to simply ask what you need - display html in razor. Ignore the jsreport part because it has nothing to do with it.